# php simple xml purser

Tags: php, xml, google-contacts-api

I am new to PHP simple XML file parser
I have an XML file like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
  <title type='text'>Aditya Technobd's Contacts</title>
  <generator version='1.0' uri='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds'>Contacts</generator>
  <entry>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
    <title type='text'>Ashfaq Ali</title>
    <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='ashfaq@technobd.com' primary='true'/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
    <title type='text'>Farhad Hossain</title>
    <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='info@rpi-rangpur.com' primary='true'/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I need the output looks like this

Name : Ashfaq Ali
email : ashfaq@technobd.com

Name : Farhad Hossain
email : info@rpi-rangpur.com

I try it blow code cannot find any clue

```
$contacts = file_get_contents("public/temporary/contacts_sample.xml");
       $feed = simplexml_load_string($contacts);
       foreach($feed->entry as $entry){
           echo "Name: " .$entry->title; 
           echo "<br>";
       }
```

can anybody help me how can I get the email address

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this question

```
$contacts = file_get_contents("public/temporary/contacts_sample.xml");
       $feed = simplexml_load_string($contacts);
       foreach($feed->entry as $entry){
           echo "Name: " .$entry->title; 
           echo "<br>";
           echo "Email: " .$entry->children('gd', TRUE)->email->attributes()->address;
           echo "<br>";
       }
```